# lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua

Tags: nginx, lua, jmeter

**The nginx.conf file looks like this:**

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  auto;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


load_module modules/ndk_http_module.so;
load_module modules/ngx_http_lua_module.so;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;

proxy_buffering on; 
proxy_buffer_size 4k;
proxy_buffers 32 4k; 
proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

proxy_read_timeout 3600;
keepalive_timeout 10m;
proxy_connect_timeout  600s;
fastcgi_send_timeout 600s;
send_timeout 600;
fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

lua_package_path "./lua/?.lua;;";
#    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


log_format main2 '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
    '\n\n"$request" \n status: $status body_bytes_sent: $body_bytes_sent '
    '\n\n http_referer:  "$http_referer" \n "$http_user_agent" $request_time '
    '\n\n req_headers: \n "$req_headers" \n\n req_body: \n "$req_body" \n\n resp_body: \n "$resp_body"';


    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main2;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

#    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

#    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {

        server_name xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com;

        listen 80;


  lua_need_request_body on;

        
        set $resp_body "";
        set $req_body "";
        set $req_headers "";

        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        client_max_body_size 16k;

        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            local req_headers = "Headers: ";
            ngx.var.req_body = ngx.req.get_body_data();
            local h, err = ngx.req.get_headers()
            for k, v in pairs(h) do
                req_headers = req_headers .. k .. ": " .. v .. "\n";
            end

            ngx.var.req_headers = req_headers;
        }

        body_filter_by_lua '
        local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
        ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
        if ngx.arg[2] then
          ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
        end
        ';


        location /  {
                proxy_pass https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
#               proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                proxy_ssl_ciphers GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912:HIGH:MEDIUM;
                proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/ivanovIvanIvanovich.pem;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/prkeyunitIvanov.key;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
#               proxy_redirect off;
        
#               root   html;
#               index  index.html index.htm;
            }      
    }

server {

       listen 8080;



 lua_need_request_body on;
       
                set $resp_body "";
        set $req_body "";
        set $req_headers "";

        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        client_max_body_size 16k;

        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            local req_headers = "Headers: ";
            ngx.var.req_body = ngx.req.get_body_data();
            local h, err = ngx.req.get_headers()
            for k, v in pairs(h) do
                req_headers = req_headers .. k .. ": " .. v .. "\n";
            end

            ngx.var.req_headers = req_headers;
        }

        body_filter_by_lua '
        local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
        ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
        if ngx.arg[2] then
          ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
        end
        ';



       location /  {

        proxy_pass https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                proxy_ssl_ciphers GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912:HIGH:MEDIUM;
                proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/PetrovIvanSemenovich.pem;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/prkeyunitSemenovich.key;
                proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                }

    }

server {

       listen 8585;


 lua_need_request_body on;
 
            set $resp_body "";
        set $req_body "";
        set $req_headers "";

        client_body_buffer_size 16k;
        client_max_body_size 16k;

        rewrite_by_lua_block {
            local req_headers = "Headers: ";
            ngx.var.req_body = ngx.req.get_body_data();
            local h, err = ngx.req.get_headers()
            for k, v in pairs(h) do
                req_headers = req_headers .. k .. ": " .. v .. "\n";
            end

            ngx.var.req_headers = req_headers;
        }

        body_filter_by_lua '
        local resp_body = string.sub(ngx.arg[1], 1, 1000)
        ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
        if ngx.arg[2] then
          ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
        end
        ';



       location /  {

        proxy_pass https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx.com;
              
proxy_ssl_server_name on;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Cookie $http_cookie;
                proxy_ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
                proxy_ssl_ciphers GOST2012-GOST8912-GOST8912:HIGH:MEDIUM;
                proxy_ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/Petrovich.pem;
                proxy_ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/prkeyunitPetrovich.key;



                }

    }

}
```

**error.log**

```
2023/01/23 07:50:11 [error] 3294740#3294740: *2312 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):6: attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194): in function <rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):1>, client: XX.XXX.XXX.89, server: , request: "POST /INC/zkau;jsessionid=cu9a1076567akai7q9hjr4h HTTP/1.1", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8585", referrer: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/INC/INC/scroller.zul?navigationId=INC_ApplRefund_D07_2"
2023/01/23 07:52:01 [error] 3294740#3294740: *2337 peer closed connection in SSL handshake (104: Connection reset by peer) while SSL handshaking to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XXX.89, server: , request: "POST /INC/zkau;jsessionid=1koc01pjtptx01dg6yskg6mndo HTTP/1.1", upstream: "https://XX.XXX.X.60:443/INC/zkau;jsessionid=1koc01pjtptx01dg6yskg6mndo", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8585", referrer: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/INC/INC/scroller.zul?navigationId=D04_Client"
2023/01/23 14:28:38 [error] 3294740#3294740: *2724 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):6: attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194): in function <rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):1>, client: XX.XXX.XXX.89, server: , request: "POST /INC/zkau;jsessionid=1ubqzl52zhbbz1d6zpytdgsd8i HTTP/1.1", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8585", referrer: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/INC/INC/scroller.zul?navigationId=INC_ApplRefund_D07_2"
2023/01/23 14:44:25 [error] 3294740#3294740: *2796 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):6: attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)
stack traceback:
coroutine 0:
    rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194): in function <rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):1>, client: XX.XXX.XXX.89, server: , request: "POST /INC/zkau;jsessionid=mm26zovs3fwo1xnstgy39zlhi HTTP/1.1", host: "XX.XXX.XX.XXX:8585", referrer: "http://XX.XXX.XX.XXX/INC/INC/scroller.zul?navigationId=INC_ApplRefund_D07_2"
```

**The error related to "peer closed connection in SSL handshake" was fixed by adding:**

```
proxy_ssl_session_reuse of;
```

But it can still be observed in the logs.

Now I am more interested in how to fix the error

```
[error] 3294740#3294740: *2796 lua entry thread aborted: runtime error: rewrite_by_lua(nginx.conf:194):6: attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)
stack traceback:
```

In Jmeter, this error looks like this:

```
<html>
<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
<!-- a padding to disable MSIE and Chrome friendly error page -->
```

But in Jmeter, it strongly describes what causes it. Therefore, I attached the nginx log

**I would be glad if you could help me fix these errors.**

Comment: The Lua error says that `v` is a table and therefore you cannot use `..` with it because `..` is for strings (and also works for numbers)

Comment: please read manuals and error messages befor asking for help. how can you do anything useful with the return value of a function if you don't know what that function returns. and how can you not refer to Lua's manual to find out what values you may concatenate if you're running into an error like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> attempt to concatenate local 'v' (a table value)

This is pretty obvious. You're attempting to concatenate a table value.

You can only concat table values if that table has a metatable implementing __concat, which obviously is not the case.

> Now I am more interested in how to fix the error

Well don't concat the table value.

Refer to the manual of the Lua Ngx API and you'll find that `ngx.req.get_headers()` returns a table of tables. Not a table of strings or numbers.

Run a loop over each table in the table returned by `ngx.req.get_headers()` and do your concat thing.